# Coloring tabs in Google Chrome with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, google-chrome

I'm trying to write a program in vb.net that allows me to color tabs in Google Chrome. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get started?

Comment: You do not have control over the browser and browser tabs are controlled by the browser.

Comment: I'm with @NTR, I don't think you'll be able to do this with VB.NET and Visual Studio. You would need to create some sort of theme or extension for Google Chrome in order to do that.